# Android how to make webView show pop up input dialog

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Pop up like this pic

[image]

I tried this setting but didn't work

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alert of of Javascript? Because I don't understand what you want.